# Is it possible to instance_eval compiled jruby's .class file?

Tags: jruby

I'm trying to compile our jruby project.
There is some files with dsl, which is read as text and instance_eval'ed on some object.
They seams to have been compiled to .class files too.
Is there any way to call that dsl from .class files?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there is no way to do that.